# How to use BinarySearch for List<T>

Tags: c#, list, binary-search

Let's start with this overload of List BinarySearch:

```
public int BinarySearch(T item, IComparer<T> comparer);
```

It is well known that the list should be sorted with the appropiate IComparer before using BinarySearch. But then: to search the list you will have to provide a T item. This is rather unexpected when one is used to searching items in the list based on properties of these items (i.e. using Linq or delegates/predicates). Because when I already have my T item I don't have to search it!

Now I was implementing C++ code in C# and saw that the C++ programmer used C++ style binary searches everywhere in his code as follows. First he made a new T item and gave this T item the properties he was looking for. Then he searched the list with it, to find *the index of an item in the list with the same properties*. The C++ comparer of course was adapted to these properties.

So this is a quite different way to look up items in a List. BinarySearch makes a *dummy* T item and searches for an index with which it can retrieve the *real* T item in the list. From a Linq point of view this feels unnatural.

My questions are:

Did I give a correct description of the idea behind BinarySearch?

Do you think it is possible to use a Linq style search with BinarySearch without making a dummy T item first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Did I give a correct description of the idea behind BinarySearch?`
Yes.

`Do you think it is possible to use a Linq style search with BinarySearch without making a dummy T item first?`
Not in it's current form. You could use a wrapper that would create the dummy T for you, it would only work for specific Ts, though (with parameterless constructors, etc.).

Comment: Why would this only work for specific T's, any documentation on that?

Comment: You can't (practically) have one universal creation method for all entities. You have classes with various number of constructor parameters - which one would you choose automatically? How would you supply parameters automatically? It would be easy for structs and parameterless classes, that you can restrict. In that regard it is (IMHO) way easier to simply create a dummy T - since the T can be anything.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to use the generic syntax 'where T : Basetype' and the wrapper can use the constuctors of Basetype?

Comment: And limiting the generic parameter like that will only allow specific Ts (as I have stated earlier) - only descendants of `Basetype`. The point is you would have to create the T in code for every `BaseType` you would want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's nothing similar in LINQ, but you can build your own extensions.
This example allow you to pass not a dummy item, but for instance just the property used in the original comparer:

```
public static int FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo<TElement, TKey>(
                this IList<TElement> keySortedCollection,
                TKey key,
                Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector,
                IComparer<TKey> keyComparer)
{
    int begin = 0;
    int end = keySortedCollection.Count;
    while (end > begin)
    {
        int index = (begin + end) / 2;
        TElement el = keySortedCollection[index];
        TKey currElKey = keySelector(el);
        if (keyComparer.Compare(currElKey, key) >= 0)
            end = index;
        else
            begin = index + 1;
    }
    return end;
}

public static int FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo<TElement, TKey>(
                this IList<TElement> keySortedCollection,
                TKey key,
                Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector)
{
    return FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo(keySortedCollection,
                                               key,
                                               keySelector,
                                               Comparer<TKey>.Default);
}
```

With these methods, you can give a comparison that is a subset of the one you originally used to sort the collection.

Obviously, when you're using a subset of the original comparer, you can't be sure to find a single index. So these methods return a lowerbound of binary search.

Comment: Little explanation added. (otherwise it would seem off-topic...)